# Supermicro X10DRi Beep Codes 4x beeps?

Tags: supermicro

I'm not getting anything visual when plugging a monitor in. When there is nothing plugged into the back of the machine, I'm getting a beep codes that sounds like..... Beep..........Beep .. Beep.......................Beep (this last one is in a different tone)

Again, looking through the manual, I can't seem to find information about what this beep codes means?

I also get a single beep when I plug in a USB device post-turning on, which I'm not sure what that means either? The lights on the keyboard/mouse light up though, so maybe these single beeps don't mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

> Again, looking through the manual, I can't seem to find information about what this beep codes means?

You seem to describe two from only five possible beep codes found in Appendix A from [the X10DRi usermanual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1491.pdf)

[image: Appendix A]

Comment: Yeah that is what I was looking through. Nothing quite seemed to match up. Anyhow, I removed all PCIe cards, then re-added them one by one, that seemed to get the system up and running. Something must not have been seated correctly.